# Get Uploader name

Tags: c#, dropbox, dropbox-api

Is it possible to get the uploader name of a file in dropbox? 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VXZd.png)
I have the following code to get file info in a form of string, yet need to parse.

```
    private string GetResponse(Uri uri)
    {
        var oauth = new OAuth();
        var requestUri = oauth.SignRequest(uri, _consumerKey, _consumerSecret, _accessToken);
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
        var response = request.GetResponse();
        var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

As I scan through the results,there is no possible entry for an uploader name. Sample file info:

```
    {
        "rev" : "1304014014338",
        "thumb_exists" : true,
        "path" : "/Screenshots/Screenshot 2015-02-09 21.48.41.png",
        "is_dir" : false,
        "client_mtime" : "Mon, 09 Feb 2015 13:48:42 +0000",
        "icon" : "page_white_picture",
        "read_only" : false,
        "modifier" : null,
        "bytes" : 321551,
        "modified" : "Mon, 09 Feb 2015 13:49:10 +0000",
        "size" : "314 KB",
        "root" : "dropbox",
        "mime_type" : "image/png",
        "revision" : 77888
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `modifier` field tells you who last changed the file, but only if the file is in a shared folder.

Comment: Hi, for some reason modifier name are not displayed when a file is being moved. And I found out the 'file move' more info can be found on events. Is it possible to get access on the dropbox events?

Comment: Are you talking about dropbox.com/events? There's no programmatic access to that. We'll investigate the missing modifier on move.

Comment: Yes, I am referring to dropbox.com/events

Comment: @WylanOsorio, I can't reproduce the issue with moving files. I tried renaming a file in an existing shared folder and also moving a new file into a shared folder. In both cases, the metadata showed me as the modifier of the file. Could you explain in more detail what issue you're seeing?